# How to update HTML text by button?

Tags: javascript, button, text

this is what i achieved so far. With the button i can get scores to add up to total. but at the Score it is not updated everytime.

```
 <script>
    function True(){
        score5=1;
            alert("Correct");   
        total=score1+score2+score3+score3+score5;
        }
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="True" onClick="True()">

    <h2>Score:<script>document.write(total)</script><h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) will run when the page is being parsed by the browser, way before the `True()` function is run. You need to give an id to your `h2`, then use that to set its [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) to the calculated score inside `True()`:

```js
// dummy values
var score1 = 5, score2 = 4, score3 = 3, score4 = 2;

function True(){
    score5=1;
    alert("Correct");   
    total=score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5;
    document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "Score: " + total.toString();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="True" onClick="True()" />

<h2 id="score">Score: 0<h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a `<script>` tag, have a `<span>` tag and give it an ID:

```
<h2>Score: <span id="totalscore"></span>
```

Now have your function edit the HTML of that span like so:

```
document.getElementById("totalscore").innerHTML = total;
```